# Bad and deteriorating TV signal

Tags: wiring, home-theater, television

I use a WISI OR 152 set-top box to receive a [DVB-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVB-C) TV signal.

A couple of months ago I rearranged my living room and as a result I had to connect the receiver to the wall outlet with a rather long (~4m) cable. Probably not surprisingly, signal quality deteriorated significantly. However, what I do *not* understand is the following: I have the impression that the signal is getting *worse* over time in general and seems to change over the day as well (better in the morning, worse in the evening).

**My question is**: What could be the reason for this and what can I do about it? Should I buy a higher quality cable?  Or are there any signs that in fact the receiver might be the culprit?

To describe the current situation in more detail: There are some channels with in general quite good (audio and video) quality. However, in particular during evenings, even when watching these channels sometimes the video freezes and there are "squeaking" noises distorting the audio signal. Other channels suffer from much stronger distortions, up to a point where there seems to be no signal at all.

One of the channels with less distortions:
[image: Little distortions]

One of the channels with mediocre signal quality (but in the morning where the signal seems to be rather good):
[image: Mediocre signal quality]

One of the very bad channels:
[image: No / bad signal]

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting both ends of the rather long cable? Be careful not to over-tighten. Is it the case that all the higher-numbered channels are worse than the lower-numbered channels? Could you, just to test, put the old cable back on and let us know if the signal is better?

Comment: assuming this is a paid cable situation, if you can't figure it out get the cable company to come look. In any case this does not seem on-topic for this site. maybe electronics.stackexchange?

Comment: Swap to a new cable. It's not the length of the cable, it's very likely that the particular cable is damaged or of poor quality.

Comment: 4m is not a long cable, I would verify the connectors are good I have seen the cheap screw in connectors cause all kinds of problem. The other thing is what type of cable different types have different impedance values RG6 75 ohm cable is the standard for most recievers. rg59 75 ohms, th 58 52 ohms, the all look close to the same but rg58 will cause problems or I have seen problems with the wrong cable type.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Reconnecting both ends does not make a difference. No, I don't see a pattern regarding high vs. low numbered channels. However, I realized that several "channels" are stuffed into the same "transponder" (sorry, not sure about the terminology; on the pictures this is called "Kanal") and all the very bad channels are on transponder 38. Couldn't test the old cable because this requires moving TV, receiver and so on which is … complicated.
I ordered a new cable, as suggested by Ecnerwal.

Comment: @EdBeal I don't know the impedance of the cable. I only know that it looks like [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31FbXiw%2BlhL._SX425_.jpg) (but that's probably not very helpful) …

Comment: @agentp Hm, it's definitely not on topic at electronic.SE. 
I'd rather keep the cable company out of this, because they will most likely blame my landlord (or my cable) instead of doing something constructive. But of course, if nothing else helps, I'll contact them.

Comment: @CL. I see {Kanal S24 (330.0 MHz) C/N 29 dB}, {Kanal S32 (394.0 MHz) C/N 26 dB}, {Kanal S38 (442.0 MHz) C/N 0 dB} as indicating that there is a frequency-dependent problem. It *could* have been due to a poor connection, which would have led to a cheap fix by re-doing the connections. I suggested changing to the old cable because you know it is a good cable - there was a chance it would have been easy to do. Please come back and let us know if the new cable solves the problem.

Comment: @andrew Morton sorry, almost forgot to reply. A new cable solved the issue. If you want to post an answer along these lines I'll happily accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @CL. It was Ecnerwal who suggested a new cable before I'd gone through ways to avoid paying for a new one, so I don't feel I can take any credit. I can't speak for him, but I and I suspect him wouldn't be upset about you answering the question yourself and then coming back to mark it as the accepted answer.